# image size on device is different after uploaing image on server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, alassetslibrary

I am doing following operation before uploading image. If I check size of image before uploading and after uploading it gets double(i.e if I have uploaded 2 MB image I can see 4 MB image on server).

```
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [assetDate timeIntervalSince1970];
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [temp defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    StrPath = [StrPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d.%@",(int)timeInterval,strImageType];

    UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:[rep scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[rep orientation]];
    NSData *dataObj = nil;
    dataObj = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    NSString* StrFileData = [Base64 encode:dataObj];
    NSString* strFileHash = [dataObj md5Test];
```

Comment: I guess it depends on encoding.

Comment: CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage]; this line is affecting anyway do you think @AKV

Comment: I am not sure... you can change and check also Base64 and others, also try to compress the image by UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)

Comment: no i don't need compressed image i need same size before and after uploading

Comment: take UIImageView  and  `imgeView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`

Answer (score 0):

Use following method for specific **hight** and **width** with **image**

```
+ (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image withWidth:(int)width withHeight:(int)height
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    float widthRatio = newSize.width/image.size.width;
    float heightRatio = newSize.height/image.size.height;

    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*heightRatio,image.size.height*heightRatio);
    }
    else
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*widthRatio,image.size.height*widthRatio);
    }


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

This method return **NewImage**, It will not be resiz :)

Answer (score 0):

I have few suggestions. If you note these.. It should help you

1. You can get the ALAsset image NSData directly from ALAsset **defaultRepresentation**

   **getBytes:fromOffset:length:error:** method.
2. Use  ALAsset thumbnail image instead of retrieving full resolution image

   **CGImageRef iref = [myasset aspectRatioThumbnail];**
3. ALAsset Libraay block will execute in seperate thread. So do the server upload in main thread

   ```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

      // do the server upload

     });
   ```